# Rejecting peripheral touch inputs

Tags: android, android-layout

Given a nested view structure such as:

[image: Nested app layout]

How do I disable input on the grey periphery, such that even as the user holds a finger on it, but touches the yellow view, the touch event would register in `dispatchTouchEvent()` for that view unhindered?

**EDIT**:
To explain a bit further, I need some kind of palm rejection system in the grey area. In the yellow area the user is able to draw with his finger. All of that works fine, but on some phones with border-less displays you might accidentally touch the grey area, which registers as input and the drawing is ruined.

This happens only when the user is touching the screen in multiple places at once. One might blame the user at this point for buying into the gimmick, but I've tried it myself and it's really easy to accidentally touch the edge, and prevent events from flowing properly.

After I've posted this question, I have come up with a somewhat hacky solution that uses multi-touch events. It works better than before, but because it's not really a multi-touch event, sometimes it goes stale and stops registering inputs altogether. Besides, it would be nice to be able to capture real multi-touch events in the yellow box eventually (for example to make zoom-into-your-drawing gesture).

The basic premise of my solution so far is:

1. Setup the view. In this test case I just got one View, that draws all the areas in its `onDraw()`.
2. Capture the `MotionEvent` in `dispatchTouchEvent()`
3. Pick out the portion of the event with the x,y inside the yellow area:

Then:

```
// ... event:MotionEvent, pointerCoordsOut:MotionEvent.PointerCoords
for (pidx in 0 until event.pointerCount) {
    event.getPointerCoords(pidx, pointerCoordsOut)
    if (inYellowArea(pointerCoordsOut.x, pointerCoordsOut.y)) {
         //pointerCoordsOut now has (x,y) that I need
    }
}
```

Finally, adjust the code to accept `ACTION_*` and `ACTION_POINTER_*` events, and make them do something reasonable. This was easy enough in the demo case, but I think this is where the solution will ultimately fail.

So I would still love for there to be a *proper* solution for palm rejection on borders as-if that event was not there at all, as opposed to in my case part of a complicated gesture that I am trying to decipher.

**EDIT**:

Still open for suggestions.

Comment: do i understand it correctly, you want to receive touch events on grey in dispatchTouchEvent but not to propagate them to onTouch?

Comment: If the user touches the grey area without touching the yellow area then slides his finger over to the yellow area you want to record a touch in the yellow area but not the grey area. Touching the grey area by itself doesn't record a touch. Is that the scenario?

Comment: @Rainmaker - I want the grey touch events completely ignored, asif they didn't happen at all. What happens in my app, is that the user accidentally touches the edge of the screen and it causes confusion because she is supposed to draw a line in the yellow section. Samsung S9 is the culprit here, with edges that stick out, but I can't find a way to ignore those accidental edge inputs.

Comment: @Cheticamp - please see my comment above. The problem happens because the user accidentally touches the right hand side of the screen when, say, drawing a line from left to right.

Comment: @Gleno why use `dispatchTouchEvent()`? Why not just use `onInterceptTouchEvent()` on the yellow view or something?

Comment: @C0D3LIC1OU5 Because he need full disable parentView's touch events.

Comment: @kovac777 so I am hearing that he needs to capture all the events so he can discard some of them, is that what you mean? My point is that using `onInterceptTouchEvent()` (for example) only on the yellow view directly leverages the Android system to only send events that are relevant to OP.

Comment: @C0D3LIC1OU5 As I understand he want to full ignore parent's touch events

Comment: Just add the valid pointer Id's to a list and remove them when the event finishes or when you don't want the pointer anymore and to get the actual event.x and y use index = event.findPointerIndex(validID) event.getX(index) and event.getY(index)

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED:**
layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/orange"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val touchableRect = Rect()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        root.post {
            orange.getGlobalVisibleRect(touchableRect)
        }

        root.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            Log.d("logi", "root touched : ${event.actionMasked}")
            false
        }

        orange.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            Log.d("logi", "orange touched : ${event.actionMasked}")
            true
        }
    }

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        val isConsumed = ev?.let {
            if (touchableRect.contains(it.x.toInt(), it.y.toInt())) {
                orange.dispatchTouchEvent(it)
            } else {
                true
            }
        }

        return isConsumed ?: true
    }
}
```

Comment: This redirects the input from the periphery to the inner view. I would rather have it ignored compeltely, even if you are touching the grey surface it should just be ignored, and if you are at the same time touching the yellow surface, those touch events are the ones that I want to fire.

Comment: @Gleno Ahh.. Ok, now i understand what are you want. Later I'll try change my code for your perpose.

Comment: this answer is wrong, and doesn't answer the posed problem. The only resolution I was able to find had to do with manually interpretering multi-touch events. It works in my case, because the drawings are supposed to be made with a single finger; however it's just a bad solution also.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is two-fold: First, a touch outside of the drawing area will fail to ever reach the drawing area for the duration of the gesture unless coding is in place to redirect the gesture. Second, there may be several pointers on the screen, so they have to be kept straight.

In the following solution, `dispatchTouchEvent()` is called for the drawing area from the main activity. This insures that the drawing area sees all events even those that are intiated outside of its boundaries. `MainActivity` does a blanket call to the drawing area although it could be made smarter to dispatch the call under certain circumstances.

The drawing area is a simple custom view that sorts through the events and acts on ones that are germane while ignoring others. See the comments in the code. The custom view simply permits the user to draw with a finger.

The main activity, the layout and the custom view all work together as a simple app if you want to try it out.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private View mDrawingArea;
    private final int[] mDrawingAreaLocation = new int[2];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        mDrawingArea = findViewById(R.id.drawing_area);

        layout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawingArea.getLocationOnScreen(mDrawingAreaLocation);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Everything goes to the drawing area. We could do some bounds checking and send
        // everything within the bounds to the drawing area and everything else to
        // super.dispatchTouchEvent().

        // Adjust location to be view-relative.
        event.offsetLocation(-mDrawingAreaLocation[0], -mDrawingAreaLocation[1]);
        return mDrawingArea.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

**MyView.java**

```
public class MyView extends View {
    private final Rect mViewBounds = new Rect();
    private static final int NO_POINTER_CAPTURED = -1;
    private int mCapturedPointer = NO_POINTER_CAPTURED;
    private final Path mPath = new Path();
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    public MyView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        mViewBounds.left = 0;
        mViewBounds.top = 0;
        mViewBounds.right = w;
        mViewBounds.bottom = h;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Coordinates will be relative to the view.

        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // This is the start of the gesture and the first pointer down.
                // Check to see if it is in our drawing area and capture it if it is.
                if (mViewBounds.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
                    mCapturedPointer = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());
                    mPath.reset();
                    mPath.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                // This is the second, third, etc. pointer down. We are just going to
                // consider capturing it if we don't have another pointer already captured.
                if (mCapturedPointer == NO_POINTER_CAPTURED) {
                    int x = (int) event.getX(event.getActionIndex());
                    int y = (int) event.getY(event.getActionIndex());
                    // The pointer must be within the drawing area.
                    if (mViewBounds.contains(x, y)) {
                        mPath.reset();
                        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
                        mCapturedPointer = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());
                    }
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // See if our captured pointer is moving. If it is, do some prep for drawing.
                if (mCapturedPointer != NO_POINTER_CAPTURED) {
                    int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
                    for (int ptrIndex = 0; ptrIndex < pointerCount; ptrIndex++) {
                        if (event.getPointerId(ptrIndex) == mCapturedPointer) {
                            mPath.lineTo(event.getX(ptrIndex), event.getY(ptrIndex));
                            invalidate();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                // Release the captured pointer when it leaves the surface.
                if (event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) == mCapturedPointer) {
                    mCapturedPointer = NO_POINTER_CAPTURED;
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                mCapturedPointer = NO_POINTER_CAPTURED;

            default:
                break;
        }

        // We want to look at everything.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/parentGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:padding="32dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.example.android.rejectperipheraltouches.MyView
        android:id="@+id/drawing_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#FDD835"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</FrameLayout>
```

***Using a touch listener***

The code above redirects events within `dispatchTouchEvent()` in the activity but may need additional logic for more complicated layouts. An alternative is to call the drawing view's `onTouchEvent()` directly from a touch listener for the parent view. Thus, if the drawing view is touched directly, all events flow normally. However, if the initial touch is to the enclosing view, those touches will be redirected to the drawing view. This is probably cleaner than the `dispatchTouchEvent()` solution.

**MainActivity.java (alternative)**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private View mDrawingArea;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawingArea = findViewById(R.id.drawing_area);
        findViewById(R.id.parentGroup).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                event.offsetLocation(-mDrawingArea.getLeft(), -mDrawingArea.getTop());
                return mDrawingArea.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
    }
}
```